# Insert schema as first row to result of hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I there a way to add schema/column headers as the first row to the output of a Hive query?

Im doing a typical dump to a local directory using this hive statement

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/some_path/'
SELECT
    ... AS column1
    ... AS column2
...
;
```

In the output I want:

```
column1    column2
data       data
data       data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **set hive.cli.print.header=true;** works only on terminals, it will not print the headers into the file. I would do this in order to achieve that :

```
bin/hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from demo;" > /path/to/file
```